# Does recommend work with Both M1 and M2 after successful Data migration using data migration tool?

Tags: magento2.3.3, development, magento1.9.2.3, data-migration-tool

We are under developing Magento 2.3.3 website, still Magento 1.9 site live. After successful Data migration using data migration tool from m1 to m2.

Note :  Still m1 live upcoming 5 months as well as working with magento 2.3.3. 
Is my workout recommend?

Answer (score 1):

do your customizations in `child` theme, keeping all overrides and css changes separate.

Comment: After completion of data migration using data migration tool, is it m1 orders reflect in m2  if new order placed in m1 after completion of data migration?

Comment: yes, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

Comment: okay, is recommend work with both version?